# Win32_Service.Create always returns 21 error code

Tags: powershell, service

I am trying to create a win service to local/remote machine using WMI, but `Win32_Service.Create` returns to me 21 [error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389390(v=vs.85).aspx) and I don't have any ideas what is wrong with input parameters:

```powershell
$connection = new-object System.Management.ConnectionOptions
$connection.EnablePrivileges = $true
$connection.Impersonation = "Impersonate"

# at the moment I test creation on local machine
$scope = new-object System.Management.ManagementScope("\\.\root\cimv2", $connection)
$scope.Connect()

$managment = new-object System.Management.ManagementClass(
    $scope, 
    (new-object System.Management.ManagementPath("Win32_Service")),
    (new-object System.Management.ObjectGetOptions))

$params = $managment.GetMethodParameters("Create")

$params["Name"] = "Test"
$params["PathName"] = "C:\Users\User\test.exe"
$params["ServiceType"] = 0x10
$params["ErrorControl"] = 1 
$params["StartMode"] = "Automatic"
# other params will be used by default

# result is 21
$result = $managment.InvokeMethod("Create", $params)   
# resultObj.ReturnValue is 21 
$resultObj = $managment.InvokeMethod("Create", $params, $null)
```

I cannot use `New-Service` because I want install service to local machine and to remote. I don't have administrator privileges (I am in WMI group) on remote machine, so I cannot use `sc`, however `sc` works fine on local machine

Does anyone have ideas what is wrong with input parameters?

Comment: Why someone downvote this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was surprise me that `DisplayName` parameter cannot be `empty` it must be set.
So parameters is bellow work fine:

```powershell
$params["Name"] = "Test"
$params["DisplayName"] = "Diplay name"
$params["PathName"] = "C:\Users\User\test.exe"
$params["ServiceType"] = 0x10
$params["ErrorControl"] = 1 
$params["StartMode"] = "Automatic"
# other params will be used by default
```